# Copy column from excel worksheets to a single worksheet

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an  excel file where I would like to summarize data automatically from all available worksheets (other than the summary).  It seems like a 3D reference should work, but it seems to only work for combining values under a math function, not for outputting a grid of values.

Here is the code I would like to work.

```
='Co:Ni'!J17:J20
```

Ideally, this would give me a column for each worksheet from Co-Ni.  This should be output to the summary sheet as a N by 4 grid.

Answer (score 0):

This 3D reference won't create the 4x4 grid you're trying for. You'd need to reference the J17:J20 cells in each sheet on a separate column of the summary sheet. As written, the 3D reference tries to put the cell values from N sheets into the same 4 cells of the summary sheet.

You might try using the INDIRECT() function on N columns, referencing J17:J20. You could list each sheet name in column A, then build your formula such that it references the sheet in column A and the data range on the sheet.

If cell A1  contains "CO" then

=INDIRECT("'"&A$1&"'!$J$17:$J$20")

will return your first result. Copy the formula across for the remaining sheet names in row 1.

Comment: This is non-ideal but might be my best bet.  If there was a way to list all the other sheet names, this would give me what I want.

Comment: How many sheets in the workbook? And, are you working with multiple workbooks? If we're talking about many sheets and multiple workbooks, then a VBA solution might be better.